# DBRef records can be queried using any other parameters, such as "name", instead of the ID

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

In Mongodb

1. In a collection having the records with a DBRef value, try to find out a way to query the field on the "name" parameter, instead of the ID.
2. In case, there is no other way to query the records for the DBRef except the ID, provide a valid/official documentation stating the reason behind it,
3. For reference, there is a library for ReactJS, called Mongoose, where the DBRef records can be queried using any other parameters, such as "name", instead of the ID. Try to find out if there is any other alternative for the same in SpringBoot.

The above mentioned tasks are listed in descending order of priority.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is targeted for the official mongodb client library for Java (found here: https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/java/)

1. Yes, you can. Basically you can query on any property using the following statement (as described in the docs): `Document student1 = gradesCollection.find(new Document("name", "NameXY")`
2. As stated in 1. it is possible.
3. That is not correct. ReactJS is a frontend framework, mongoose is a library to be included in node.js.

Note: If you are using Spring Data MongoDB you have the possibilites to derive queries from function names (as explained in https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/ under "Create Simple Queries). There is actually an example where the exact use case you stated is contained.

Comment: I need a mongodb query to search in studio 3t GUI,using any other parameters, such as "name", instead of the ID.

Comment: Well, you can simply pass in `db.getCollections("collectionName").find({name: "nameXY"})` in order to query in 3T. I am not sure what the actual problem is here.

Comment: Then you should swap "collectionName" with "asset". I think your question (which is not really a question though), is lacking important information here.

Comment: Sorry it was incomplete

Comment: 2 collection = asset and assetVersion, both having fields like asset has {_id, name, url} , assetVersion has {id, asset, operation, message},as you can see asset is holding the DBref in assetVersion, when user updated name or url in asset table, a new entry will be created in assetVersion table for that same element with different id, if a user wants to list all the versions of the particular asset, They need to take the id of this version and list it assetVersion table, But the problem is we do not disclose the id of any entry of the db to the user, We want to run a query instead of asset.id

Comment: This is the question continued from above one,any idea?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know what your exact question ist. SO is not a platform where people write code for you. You should at least provide some effort, like what you tried and what error you are facing. You should also include this in your original question and don‘t „hide“ it in some comments.